# Visual C++ Express Brace-Completion

Tags: c++, visual-c++, autocomplete, express, braces

I really like the Visual C++ Express Version for efficient C++-Coding. I'm just missing the feature of auto brace-completion, for example when I type
{
and press enter ist should automatically add
}.
I googled a Lot but just found Addons for the professional or the C#-Versions. Isn't there any possibility of getting this to work? I'm really wondering why this isn't already a standard feature since it's either not that of an act to implement it and also in the C#-Edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not available in the Visual Studio C++ editor. Atleast if you have the express edition. Using the other versions, like you have said, makes it possible to download or create an addin/extension to get to this result.

As mentioned in: [visual studio 2010 C++ : braces autocomplete](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/e882f1fd-3a78-40e3-a169-2eadd9bfae3b/)

Should you decide to switch to a different version of Visual Studio 2010 I can recommend this addin: [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/) which allows a lot of customization, including automatic brackets.

Comment: Hmm, okay. It's not a solution for me to buy the professional edition. I don't want to pay 500€ or more just to have that one feature. Thank you!

Comment: If you are a student you can get it for free from dreamspark I believe. I couldn't find your age on your profile so decided to suggest this :)

Comment: Oh im really thankful for this advice! I never heard of dreamspark before, really gonna Check this out :-)